# Parse pipes when in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split a string where the delimiter is a pipe.
But the pipe can be escaped and not splitted than.

example:

```
'aa|bb|cc'.split(/*??*/) // ['aa','bb','cc']
'aa\|aa|bb|cc|dd\|dd|ee'.split(/*??*/) // ['aa|aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd|dd', 'ee']
```

I try this, but it not work in javascript: `(?<!\\)[\|]`

Comment: Go with `match`.

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
    console.log('aa|bb|cc'.split('|'));
    console.log('aa\|aa|bb|cc|dd\|dd|ee'.split('|'));
```

Comment: var result = 'aa\|aa|bb|cc|dd\|dd|ee'.split('|');

Comment: it not work. I want this `['aa|aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd|dd', 'ee']` and I get this: `["aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "dd", "ee"]`

Comment: @Rajaswami:  and how could we possibly know what you were expecting? Did you include the desired result with your question?

Comment: Yes he did. Just look at code comments and read question more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to skip splitting on escaped pipes. Use `match` instead:

```js
console.log(
  'aa\\|aa|bb|cc|dd\\|dd|ee'.match(/[^\\|]*(?:\\.[^\\|]*)*/g).filter(Boolean)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the Regex I created

https://www.regexpal.com/index.php?fam=100132

What you need to do is concact the matches in an array

the code generated looks like this...

```
const regex = /(([^\\\|]+)\\?\|\2)|(\w+)/g;
const str = `aa\\|aa|bb|cc|dd\\|dd|ee`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
// This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
}

// The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
});
```

}

Hope this help you.